# Using ITRANS postscript fonts with MikTeX2.9

Tags: miktex, dvips, indic

I have followed John Washburn's instructions from the document ITRANS53 Installation Notes with MiKTEX 2.9 (http://www.aczoom.com/files/itrans/mirror/itransi-MiKTeX/itransi-MiKTeX.pdf).

I can convert .itx to .tex but when I run

dvips gujdoc.dvi -o

the output says it cannot find itxguj source file. What should I do?

Trying to make PK font itxguj at 900 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The itxguj source file could not be found.

Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk: PK font itxguj could not be created.

This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2014.04.25:1846' -> gujdoc.ps
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\dvips.exe: Font itxguj not found; characters will be left blank.

. 








[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]

Comment: The installation script as it is shown in your pdf is faulty. It doesn't copy a map file, it doesn't add this map file to a updmap.cfg. Also it is not a good idea to install the fonts in the main miktex roots. Such local packages should go to a local root.

Answer (score 2):

By, *I can convert .itx to .tex*, I am assuming you have issued the following command

```
itrans -i gujdoc.itx -o gujdoc.tex
```

The command sequence I think you need is

```
itrans -i gujdoc.itx -o gujdoc.tex 
texify gujdoc.tex 
dvips gujdoc.dvi -o
```

- The first command converts the Romanized trans-literations into a TeX
  file that properly references and marks up characters from an Indic
  language (Gujarati I am guessing).
- The second command converts the
  TeX file in to a DVI (DeVice Independent) file which can be viewed
  using YAP which was installed when MikTeX was installed.
- The third command converts the DVI file into a postscript (PS) file.

Did the gujdoc.tex file compile into the gujdoc.dvi file without error?

I would also try issuing the following texify command

```
texify -p gujdoc.tex
```

This will create the file *gujdoc.pdf*, which may not be what you want, but it is my understanding that a side effect of creating a PDF file with *textify -p* is that all the postscript fonts referenced are created and registered.  If the font is registered, then it should be available to the *dvips* command.